# Swift: Can't use nested/chained generic type constraints (Policy pattern)

Tags: swift, generics, policy, swift2

I'm implementing a randomized tree data structure in Swift. To constrain tree's width and depth, I have decided to use the *Policy (Strategy) pattern*.

My policy looks like this:

```
protocol BaseTreeNodePolicy {
    static var maximumDepth: Int { get }
    static var maximumWidth: Int { get }
}
```

and I have a base class which looks like this:

```
class BaseTreeNode<PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy> { /* ... */ }
```

some subclasses of it:

```
class ValueNode<ValueType, PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy>: BaseTreeNode<PolicyType> { /* ... */ }
class ActionNode<PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy>: BaseTreeNode<PolicyType> { /* ... */ }
```

Everything has worked well until I added this class:

```
final class SequenceNode<ChildType: ActionNode<PolicyType>, PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy>: ActionNode<PolicyType> {
    public var sequence: [ChildType] = []
    // ...
    public override func addRandomDescendants(generator: EntropyGenerator, maxDepth: Int) {
        // ...
        sequence.reserveCapacity(42)
        // ...
        let descendant = ChildType(generator: generator, maxDepth: maxDepth - 1)
        // ...
    }
}
```

When compiling `SequenceNode`, I get compiler errors on this row:

```
// 'ChildType' is not a subtype of 'ActionNode<PolicyType>'
sequence.reserveCapacity(42)
```

and this row:

```
// Type 'PolicyType' does not conform to protocol 'BaseTreeNodePolicy'
let descendant = ChildType(generator: generator, maxDepth: maxDepth - 1)
```

I have no idea what's wrong as I clearly state the type requirements saying that `ChildType: ActionNode<PolicyType>` and `PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy` right in the header part of the declaration.

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!
Petr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Re-do to get to your intent:

`ActionNode<PolicyType>` doesn't belong in the parameter list. You're only parameterizing on `PolicyType`:

```
final class SequenceNode<PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy> {
    typealias ChildType = ActionNode<PolicyType>
    var sequence = [ChildType]()
    func addRandomDescendants(generator: EntropyGenerator, maxDepth: Int) {
        sequence.reserveCapacity(42)
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Now you want to be more generic. OK, but you don't get to chain type dependencies *WITHIN* a generic type constraint list. The type constraints must be resolvable directly. This should make the error clear:

```
class _ERROR_SequenceNode<PolicyType, ChildType where PolicyType: BaseTreeNodePolicy, ChildType: ActionNode<PolicyType>> { }
```

> Superclass constraint 'ActionNode' cannot depend on a type parameter

However, you *ALSO* cannot use `BaseTreeNodePolicy` in place of `PolicyType` because it's not concrete:

> Using 'BaseTreeNodePolicy' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'BaseTreeNodePolicy' is not supported

So, since `ChildType` is already constrained already by a generic type, that generic type must be *instantiable directly*, hence it can only be itself constrained by a known, outside, *concrete* implementation of `BaseTreeNodePolicy`.

***BIG PICTURE***

However, I think you're getting tangled in generics while missing the idea of just getting the job done simply. There is no value in parameterizing through generics *when you have full control of that branch of the type system*, and *you don't need to return the ***ACTUAL*** genericized type from a function*.

In other words, I must build a hash table generically parameterized on `FooKeyType` where `FooKeyType: Hashable` because users of my class rightfully expect the return value from a `getKey()` function to be the actual type in *their* code, not of type `Hashable`. Here, you don't ever return the `policy` object, or even if you did, you shouldn't care that its return type is fixed at `BaseTreeNodePolicy` rather than some specific, concrete policy type.

You can constrain simply by abstractly type-constraining the stored property as the requisite protocol.

Consider:

```
protocol BaseTreeNodePolicy {
    var maximumDepth: Int { get }
    var maximumWidth: Int { get }
}

class BaseTreeNode {
    var policy: BaseTreeNodePolicy

    required init(policy: BaseTreeNodePolicy) {
        self.policy = policy
    }

    // Use 'policy' anywhere now. You've defined a protocol, don't generically parameterize
}

class ValueNode: BaseTreeNode {
    required init(policy: BaseTreeNodePolicy) {
        super.init(policy: policy)
    }
}

class ActionNode: BaseTreeNode {
    required init(policy: BaseTreeNodePolicy) {
        super.init(policy: policy)
    }
}

class SequenceNode<ChildType: ActionNode>: BaseTreeNode {
    var sequence: [ChildType] = []

    required init(policy: BaseTreeNodePolicy) {
        super.init(policy: policy)
    }

    func addRandomDescendants() {
        let c = ChildType(policy: policy)
        sequence.reserveCapacity(42)
    }
}

class FooNode: ActionNode {}

class MyPolicy: BaseTreeNodePolicy {
    var maximumDepth = 3
    var maximumWidth = 5
}

let s = SequenceNode<FooNode>(policy: MyPolicy())
```

Comment: It's simpler than I thought, try this.

Comment: Nice solution, but what do I do if I want `ChildType` to be any subclass of `ActionNode<PolicyType>`?

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed and comprehensive answer. That's exactly what I wanted. I just didn't realize that a policy can be instantiated (I have background in C++ where you can have way more fun with these things). I hope that it helps other developers as well. :-)